# How do I read and label images stored in two different directories for binary classification?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The two directories I have contain many images, each image having a unique name. One directory is healthy, and another one is unhealthy.

I need to read images from both the directories, and label the images from one directory as 1, and 0 from another directory, then create a numpy array with each each image mapped to its corresponding label.

```
healthy = glob.glob('/path to healthy directory/' + '*.nii.gz')
unhealthy = glob.glob('path to unhealthy directory' + '*.nii.gz')

images = []

for i in healthy:
img = nib.load(i).get_fdata()
images.append(img)

for i in unhealthy:
img = nib.load(i).get_fdata()
images.append(img)
```

Comment: I have edited it. I am reading images from two different folders, depending upon the folder it was read from, a class label needs to be assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `glob.glob(/path/to/directory/**.<extension>)` to get a list of images in a directory. You might need to use more than one call if there are multiple file extensions.

Once you have a list of images, you can do

```
np.concatenate(np.array([images]), np.ones((1, len(images))))
```

or

```
np.concatenate(np.array([images]), np.zeros((1, len(images))))
```

as appropriate.

Comment: I have been able to do this bit, but I am stuck on labelling them. Images read from one directory need to be labelled as 1, and 0 from the other directory. Also, there needs to be a proper mapping between an image and its label. So, that I can tarin it properly in CNN.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) that addresses this, specifically the function you're likely looking for is [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) one. You have to use `labels=inferred` and name your directories based on the classes you're dealing with. Also, you likely don't need to use numpy arrays.  You can probably use functions from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image) to do what you need to do.  Best of luck!